# How to best handle a situation in PHP where constructor receives a mandatory non-null value, which may not always be initialized?

Tags: php, constructor, initialization, php-7, type-hinting

I have some code like so:

```
class Repository
{
    private $number;

    function __construct(int $number)
    {
        $this->number = $number;
    }

    //example where $number is required
    function readQuote()
    {
        return $this->db->runSql("select * from quote where id = $this->number");
    }
}
```

I put `$number` in constructor because `Repository` refers to a `Quote` object with a certain number and `Quote` cannot exist without the number.  Thus it makes sense to force the number being there, when `Quote` number is known.

However ... There is a situation where the number is not yet known.  Like when I first load a page and have not defined (picked/selected) the number I want to show, and yet I want the pages to load and work.

Specifically, I have code like this:

```
$controller = new Controller(new Repository($number));

//this line does not require Repository, 
//and hence $number can be uninitialized
$controller->generateIndexPage();
...

//this one does, but it is called only when number is already known
$controller->getQuote();
```

When I know the number, all works well.  When it is not yet initialized and is `null`, my code breaks with a PHP `TypeError` error (PHP Engine expects `int`, it gets `null)`.

**Question**

How do I deal with this situation?

**Thoughts**

Two solutions I can think of are

- initialize $number to `-1`, which will keep PHP happy but it is also a magic value and as such I am thinking it is not desirable
- change my constructor to say `function __construct(int $number = null)`, which will get rid of `TypeError`, but it irks me on some level because I am weakening constructor to accept `null`, rather than keeping it hardened to accept `int` only.

Comment: if `$number` is mandatory for `Repository`, don't instantiate the `Repository`  unless you know the number.

Comment: thank you.  It looks like my issue is forcing a mandatory `Repository` on `Controller`, when there is a situation where it is not required, like i.e. for the `generateIndexPage()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a nod to Alex's comment on my question, I am thinking of going with this method:

Make it to where `Controller` can accept a `Repository` or a `null`, due to a situation where Repository is not a mandatory parameter for my Controller.  But keep `$number` mandatory on `Repository`.

Answer (score 0):

Give the variable a value in function parameters like this:

```
class Repository{
  private $number;

  function __construct($number = 'x'){
    // Check if the $number is provided and value of $number has changed.
    if(is_numeric($number) && $number != 'x'){numeric
      $this->number = $number;
    }
  }
}
```